# How the data only will show in the account which the data is inserted by that user?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in a database. One table is for user login and registration and the other is for user key in data.

For table user login and register has id as primary key, username, password and email while user key in data table has id as primary key and name of data. How I can do like for example, account 1 login and key in the data and the data only will show in account 1. When other account login , they will not see the data? Sorry for my bad English. I want to know how i can set the data is key in by that account in php? I am using localhost.

For insert data php

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO Table2 (name) VALUES ('$name')";
```

For Display data php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table2 ";
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a simple [**INNER JOIN**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx) combined with a **[WHERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_(SQL))** clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_information
INNER JOIN users
ON user_information.userID = users.ID
WHERE users.ID = 1;
```

This will join the two tables so you can grab the information in the `user_information` table where the ID is `1` in the `users` table.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: this one write in which php?

Comment: You would use a command similar to the one above when you are **querying** your data (and trying to display it on the page). Note that you will need to substitute the table names. `users` contains the IDs of all of your user accounts. `user_information` contains general data about your users, and is assumed to have a foreign key that matches the `ID` in the `users` table.